# Redux state overwritten after next fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers

In my web app, I want to fetch urls from an API. Also, I want to fetch categories for these items.

index.js:

```
 componentDidMount () {
   this.props.fetchUrls();
   this.props.fetchCategories();
 }
```

Im fetching the urls first like that:

```
export const fetchUrlsSuccess = urls => ({
  type: FETCH_URLS_SUCCESS,
  payload: { urls }
});

export const fetchUrls = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch(fetchUrlsBegin());

  return fetch(`${api}/urls`)
    .then(handleErrors)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(json => {
      dispatch(fetchUrlsSuccess(json));
      return json.urls;
    })
    .catch(error => dispatch(fetchUrlsFailure(error)));
};
```

fetching categories:

```
export const fetchCategoriesSuccess = categories => ({
  type: FETCH_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS,
  payload: { categories }
});

export const fetchCategoriesFailure = error => ({
  type: FETCH_CATEGORIES_FAILURE,
  payload: { error }
});

export function fetchCategories() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(fetchCategoriesBegin());
    return fetch(`${api}/categories`)
      .then(handleErrors)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        dispatch(fetchCategoriesSuccess(json));
        return json.categories;
      })
      .catch(error => dispatch(fetchCategoriesFailure(error)));
  };
}
```

url reducer:

```
import {
  FETCH_URLS_BEGIN,
  FETCH_URLS_SUCCESS,
  FETCH_URLS_FAILURE
} from "../actions/types";

export default function urlReducer(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_URLS_BEGIN:
      console.log("url fetch begin", state);
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        error: null
      };

    case FETCH_URLS_SUCCESS:
      console.log("url fetch success", state);
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        items: action.payload.urls
      };

    case FETCH_URLS_FAILURE:
      console.log("url fetch error", state);
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload.error,
        items: []
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

categories reducer:

```
import {
  FETCH_CATEGORIES_BEGIN,
  FETCH_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS,
  FETCH_CATEGORIES_FAILURE
} from "../actions/types";

export default function categoriesReducer(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_CATEGORIES_BEGIN:
      console.log("categories fetch begin", state);
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: true,
        error: null
      };

    case FETCH_CATEGORIES_SUCCESS:
      console.log("categories fetch success", state);
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        items: action.payload.categories
      };

    case FETCH_CATEGORIES_FAILURE:
      console.log("categories fetch fail", state);
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload.error,
        items: []
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

combining reducers in index of reducers:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import urlReducer from "./urlReducer";
import categoriesReducer from "./categoriesReducer";
import modalReducer from "./modalReducer";

export default combineReducers({
  urls: urlReducer,
  modal: modalReducer,
  categories: categoriesReducer
});
```

create store :

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";

import rootReducer from "../reducers";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const middleware = [thunk];

let store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
  )
);
let persistor = persistStore(store);
export { store, persistor };
```

For the categories, I do the same. Then I combine both reducers.

What happens is that the state.urls. Items get overwritten and state.categories.items holds state instead. I don't understand why.

output of the redux dev-tool after the second fetch:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQsHQ.png]

I'm pretty new to redux and don't understand the state management...

Comment: where is state.urls ? all I see is items

Comment: i posted the reducer for urls. the reducer for categories looks the same, but just for categories

Comment: are you using the same reducer for categories  and urls?

Comment: actually no. would it be helpful if i post the reducer for categories too?

Comment: No need, can you please show me how you combining the reducers ?

Comment: added some more code to the issue

Comment: Can you please also paste categories reducer? Combining looks fine

Comment: And this function also this.props.fetchCategories()

Comment: Did so. May it be possible that redux-persist is the problem?

Comment: I think so.. can you put undefined as a second argument to createStore and then try?

Comment: Ok i will try that tomorrow. If that doesnt work, maybe im going to try it first without redux-persist.

Comment: Cool let me know how that go, looks like its reset reducers on every call, maybe undefined as initial value  will fix that, sorry i couldn't help more, this is a tricky one

Comment: You wont believe what was the mistake... i mistakenly defined the types wrong. so whenever i fired fetch categories action the url reducer was called but with the state of categories... sometimes its just simple mistakes... 

But thank you very much for your effort !
By troubleshooting i really improved the code :D

Comment: the only file we didn't checked... lol